# Remove weird glitch from accordion pop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

OK, so here's a weird issue I'm facing:

- I'm using an accordion widget (pretty much 100% original bootstrap code)
- When the accordion item (menu) is expanded, it looks as if it takes some time before it gets its original shape.

Why is that?

Please have a look at here: `http://83.212.101.132/betdk/home/three`

And try expanding (clicking on the title): Soccer / World Kop 2013 menu item in the `Categories` sidebar on the left. Why is that happening?

(The exact same thing is happening when expanding accordion items in the main "Top Matches" Box).

Any suggestion is more than welcome! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this issue because you've added padding to top and bottom of the class .accordion-body:

```
.accordion-body {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

After animation finished, browser will add extra padding so you have this glitch.

To fix this you just need to remove your styles for .accordion-body and add this:

```
.accordion-inner{margin: 10px 0;}
```

Comment: OK. One word: **AWESOME**. Thanks a lot, my friend! :-)

Answer (score 0):

try adding your heading and ul li in below code and check if it works for you..

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

check http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-examples